# SocketIO with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, socket.io

I have a socketIO server that I am trying to connect to in my app and I went through the documentations and have also watched tutorials on using socketIO in flutter but nothing seems to work out for me because the tutorials and documentation all talk about peer-to-peer messaging or private messaging but I am trying to work with something similar to a room where you can get newsfeed or messages(both texts and images) from more than one person at a time. Please is there anyone or anything that can help me with this?

Comment: Making the connection works perfectly, displaying the data or messages does not

Answer (score 0):

Socketio uses events , if you want messages sent to everyone in a room you can name an event "room1" and broadcast the event to everyone in the room.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I forgot to add that from what i did with the tutorials and docs, the connection is made but the data is not displayed on screen